# Parallel order-preserving selection from an array using tbb

Tags: c++, multithreading, tbb, eigen3

I have a [range-image](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/CVonline/LOCAL_COPIES/CANTZLER2/range.html) and want to convert it into a [libpointmatcher point cloud](https://github.com/ethz-asl/libpointmatcher/blob/master/doc/Pointclouds.md). The cloud is an `Eigen::Matrix` with 4 rows (x,y,z,1) and several columns for every point. 
The range-image is an `unsigned short*`array including the range values (z) and an `unsigned char*`array including information about the pixel visibility.

In serial, my code looks like this:

```
//container to hold the data
std::vector<Eigen::Vector4d> vec;
vec.reserve(this->Height*this->Width);

//contains information about pixel visibility
unsigned char* mask_data = (unsigned char*)range_image.mask.ToPointer();
//contains the actual pixel data 
unsigned short* pixel_data = (unsigned short*)range_image.pixel.ToPointer();

for (int y =0;y < range_image.Height; y++)
{ 
    for (int x = 0; x < range_image.Width; x++)
    {   
        int index  =x+y*range_image.Width;
        if(*(mask_data+index) != 0)
        {               
            vec.push_back(Eigen::Vector4d(x,y,(double)*(data+index),1));
        }               
    }
}
// libpointmatcher point cloud with size of visible pixel
PM::Matrix features(4,vec.size());
PM::DataPoints::Labels featureLabels;
featureLabels.resize(4);
featureLabels[0] =  PM::DataPoints::Label::Label("x");
featureLabels[1] =  PM::DataPoints::Label::Label("y");
featureLabels[2] =  PM::DataPoints::Label::Label("z");
featureLabels[3] =  PM::DataPoints::Label::Label("pad");

//fill with data
for(int i = 0; i<vec.size(); i++)
{
    features.col(i) = vec[i];
}
```

Because of the large images this loop takes 500ms for 840000 points and thats too slow. Now my idea was to integrate the code above in one parallized function. The problem is that the `Eigen::Matrix` does not provide a `push_back` functionality, i dont know the number of visible points in advance and i need the points in the right order to process the point cloud.

So i need a  parallel algorithm to extract visible 3D-Points from my range-image and insert them into the Eigen::Matrix in the right order. I'm working with **Microsoft Visual Studio 2012** and i can use either **OpenMP 2.0** or **TBB**. I appreciate any help :)

**UPDATE**

As Arch D. Robison suggeested i tried the `tbb::parallel_scan`. I passed the mask array and a double array to hold the 3D-coodinates. The output array has  four times the size of the input array to store homogeneous 3D data (x,y,z,1). Then i map the otput array in a Eigen::Matrix.The number of rows is fixed and the cols coming from the result from the parallel_scan.

```
size_t vec_size = width*height;
double* out = new double[vec_size * 4];
size_t m1 = Compress(mask, pixel, out, height, width,
 [](unsigned char x)  {return x != 0; });
Map<MatrixXd> features(out, 4, m1);
```

. Here is the code from the `operator()`:

```
void operator()(const tbb::blocked_range2d<size_t, size_t>& r, Tag) {
    // Use local variables instead of member fields inside the loop,
    // to improve odds that values will be kept in registers.
    size_t j = sum;
    const unsigned char* m = in;
    const unsigned short* p = in2;
    T* values = out;
    size_t yend = r.rows().end();
    for (size_t y = r.rows().begin(); y != yend; ++y)
    {
        size_t xend = r.cols().end();
        for (size_t x = r.cols().begin(); x != xend; ++x)
        {
            size_t index = x + y*width;
            if (pred(m[index]))
            {
                if (Tag::is_final_scan())
                {
                    size_t idx = j*4;
                    values[idx] = (double)x;
                    values[idx + 1] = (double)y;
                    values[idx + 2] = p[index];
                    values[idx + 3] = 1.0;
                }
                ++j;
            }
        }
    }
    sum = j;
}
```

I'm now 4x faster then the serial version. What do you think about this approach? Did i miss anythink and are there improvements? Thanks

Comment: If what you need is the logical equivalent of std::copy_if, consider using tbb::parallel_scan (https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/bc/2b/parallel_scan.pdf).  The "final scan" phase can compute the final destination index (as the sum of the "success-case" indices and do the conditional assignment.

Comment: @ArchD.Robison can you give me a code example of the parallel_scan requirements (Body,reverse_join_assign)? I have no idea how to do it :/ What is the best structure to hold the indices and how do i merge them in the final scan? please help me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how to do something like `std::copy_if using` `tbb::parallel_scan`.  The key method is `operator()`, which is usually called twice per subrange, once for a prescan and once for a final scan.  (But be aware that TBB omits the prescan when it's not necessary.)  Here the prescan just does tallying and the final scan does the final work (which includes replaying the tallying).  See https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/bc/2b/parallel_scan.pdf for more details on the methods.  Another good references is https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~guyb/papers/Ble93.pdf , which shows lots of things you can do with parallel scan (a.k.a. prefix-sum).

```

```
#include "tbb/parallel_scan.h"
#include "tbb/blocked_range.h"
#include <cstddef>

template<typename T, typename Pred>
class Body {
    const T* const in;
    T* const out;
    Pred pred;
    size_t sum;
public:
    Body( T* in_, T* out_, Pred pred_) :
        in(in_), out(out_), pred(pred_), sum(0)
    {}
    size_t getSum() const {return sum;}
    template<typename Tag>
    void operator()( const tbb::blocked_range<size_t>& r, Tag ) {
        // Use local variables instead of member fields inside the loop,
        // to improve odds that values will be kept in registers.
        size_t j = sum;
        const T* x = in;
        T* y = out;
        for( size_t i=r.begin(); i<r.end(); ++i ) {
            if( pred(x[i]) ) {
                if( Tag::is_final_scan() )
                    y[j] = x[i];
                ++j;
            }
        }
        sum = j;
    }
    // Splitting constructor used for parallel fork.
    // Note that it's sum(0), not sum(b.sum), because this
    // constructor will be used to compute a partial sum.
    // Method reverse_join will put together the two sub-sums.
    Body( Body& b, tbb::split ) :
        in(b.in), out(b.out), pred(b.pred), sum(0)
    {}
    // Join partial solutions computed by two Body objects.
    // Arguments "this" and "a" correspond to the splitting
    // constructor arguments "b" and "this".  That's why
    // it's called a reverse join.
    void reverse_join( Body& a ) {
        sum += a.sum;
    }
    void assign( Body& b ) {sum=b.sum;}
};

// Copy to out each element of in that satisfies pred.
// Return number of elements copied.
template<typename T, typename Pred>
size_t Compress( T* in, T* out, size_t n, Pred pred ) {
    Body<T,Pred> b(in,out,pred);
    tbb::parallel_scan(tbb::blocked_range<size_t>(0,n), b);
    return b.getSum();
}

#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>

int main() {
    const size_t n = 10000000;
    float* a = new float[n];
    float* b = new float[n];
    float* c = new float[n];
    for( size_t i=0; i<n; ++i )
        a[i] = std::cos(float(i));
    size_t m1 = Compress(a, b, n, [](float x) {return x<0;});
    size_t m2 = std::copy_if(a, a+n, c, [](float x) {return x<0;})-c;
    assert(m1==m2);
    for( size_t i=0; i<n; ++i )
        assert(b[i]==c[i]);
}
```

```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try it as soon as possible. You justed a size of 10000000. can you say something about the performance for less values? like 1 million or just 100 thousend?

Comment: It all depends on how heavyweight the `pred` operation is for your case.  If it only a few cycles (e.g. "<" on ints), the scan is probably a losing proposition on "big-core" Xeons, because the memory transfer overhead will swamp the computation.  On a Knights Landing, there might be some hope of speedup.  If your "pred" is heavyweight, you'll have better luck.

Answer (score 0):

Why do not you check out the condition `*(m_maskData+index)==0` before `m_features(0,index) = x;`?

Comment: Yeah i will do that. The problem is that i dont know the number of visible pixel and the parallel_for does not execute in a specific order. But i need just the visible pixel in the same order as they are in the image.